# I wanted capture list of data inside FormGroup of FormArray Angular Reactive form without FormControl

Tags: angular, select, formarray

I do have quantity dropdown in my form array which is having quantityList. List of options in dropdown is varying according to selection of product.

Can push quantityList as static data array in formarray without any formcontrol.

```
HTML file

ngOnInit() {
  this.orderForm = new FormGroup({
    items: new FormArray([])
  });
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return  new FormGroup({
    productName: new FormControl(),
    price: new FormControl(),
    quantity: new FormControl(),
    quantityList: ["1","2","3"] // ['1','2'] , ['1']
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}

TS file


ngOnInit() {
  this.orderForm = new FormGroup({
    items: new FormArray([])
  });
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return  new FormGroup({
    productName: new FormControl(),
    price: new FormControl(),
    quantity: new FormControl(),
    quantityList: ["1","2","3"] // ['1','2'] , ['1']
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}
```

stackblitz URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-xt8uhx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html